# Swift: UICollectionViewCell didSelectItemAtIndexPath Change backgroundColor

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm easily able to change the background color of a cell in the `CellForItemAtIndexPath` method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
 }
```

However, when I attempt to change the color in the `DidSelectItemAtIndexPath` it does not work.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell: ButtonCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ButtonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ButtonCollectionCell {
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

}

Also I read somewhere that using `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` won't work because once the collection view begins scrolling the color will change back

What is the fix in Swift?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: have you tried calling cell.layoutIfNeeded()?

Comment: No though I'll admit I'm not familiar enough with swift to know how to solve the problem using layoutIfNeeded. @CraigStanford

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this method for that:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    var cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
}
```

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I've edited my question but I have already tried that function, and it is not changing the background, also when you scroll someone told me the colors will change

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but it can help someone:

You **can't** simply modify the cell, since your changes will be lost when you scroll your `UICollectionView`, or even worst, other cells could appear with a wrong background, because they'll be reused.

So, the best way to do that is create an array of `NSIndexPath` and append your selected indexPaths:

```
var selectedIndexes = [NSIndexPath]() {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    // ...
    if let indexSelecionado = selectedIndexes.indexOf(indexPath) {
        selectedIndexes.removeAtIndex(indexSelecionado)
    } else {
        selectedIndexes.append(indexPath)
    }
}

// ...

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // ...
    if self.selectedIndexes.indexOf(indexPath) == nil {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() // Unselected
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() // Selected
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override UICollectionViewCell isSelected . It will apply changes in selected method.

```
class ButtonCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

            override var isSelected: Bool{
                didSet{
                    if self.isSelected
                    {
                       self.layer.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0.8058760762, green: 0.2736578584, blue: 0.1300437152, alpha: 1)

                    }  else
                    {
                       self.layer.backgroundColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)

                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

let startTime = DateUtils.getDispatchTimeByDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
dispatch_after(startTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {[weak self] in
    //there is the code redirect to other viewcontroller
    openOtherVC()
}
```