# CollectionView multiple cell selection

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view with two custom cells one is for grid and one is for list, i want to be able to touch cells and select them as as if want to delete or share them , all i want for now to be able to select and deselct them, ill post my code below the result is when i touch one cell all cells are selected! here is the code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if isGridSelected {

        let cell:cell2_Class = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell2_Class

        cell.listImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

        if flag == true {
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
            cancelButton.hidden = false
        } else {
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            cancelButton.hidden = true
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell:PhotoCollectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionCell

        if flag == true {
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 3
            cancelButton.hidden = false
        } else {
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
            cancelButton.hidden = true
        }
        cell.imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.NameLabel.text = namelabel[indexPath.row]
        cell.ModifiedLbl.text = modfLabel[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if cell!.selected == true {
        flag = true
    } else {
        flag = false 
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: why not change the DS and then reload the collectionView?

Comment: thanks, but i dont quite get what you mean

Comment: It means, there surely must be some array or some kind of Data structure.
So why not change values over there and simply reload the collectionview?

Answer (score 13):

In `PhotoCollectionCell` and `cell2_Class` (or in a common `superclass`) simply override this method

```
- (void) setSelected:(BOOL)selected 
{ 
     if (selected) 
     {        
         self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
         self.layer.borderWidth = 3
     } 
     else 
     {
         self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
     }
}
```

Then you don't have to deal with the actual `selection/highlighting` in your `delegate` or `dataSource`.

Make sure to have your `collectionView` has the property `allowsSelection` to `YES`.

If you want `multiple selection` then also set `allowsMultipleSelection` to `YES` and implement the following method in your `delegate`

```
- (BOOL) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems containsObject: indexPath])
    {
        [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath: indexPath animated: YES];
        return NO;            
    }
    return YES;
}
```

#### Swift Solution

Subclass of `collectionViewCell`

```
override var selected: Bool {
    didSet {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        self.layer.borderColor = selected ? UIColor.blueColor().CGColor : UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    }
}
```

in `UICollectionViewDelegate`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let selectedItems = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems() {
        if selectedItems.contains(indexPath) {
            collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot , but can you tell me how to do that in swift, thanks agan

Comment: My swift is not up to my objective c standards, but this example should do it! =)

Comment: thanks alot man, i did implement the solution you gave me but nothing happens when i touch a cell

Comment: Thank you all for your help :) ,, followed this solution and it worked thank u all again :)     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28596859/swift-uicollectionviewcell-didselectitematindexpath-change-backgroundcolor?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Based on Aerows solution
**Swift 4.2**

Subclass of `collectionViewCell`

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
            self.layer.borderColor = isSelected ? UIColor.blue.cgColor : UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }
    }
```

in `UICollectionViewDelegate`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let selectedItems = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
        if selectedItems.contains(indexPath) {
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

And very important, on your `viewDidLoad()` don't forget to allow your collectionView multiple selection

```
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

[Apple documentation - allowsMultipleSelection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618024-allowsmultipleselection)